# How can I hide the autocomplete box in tablet chrome

Tags: html

[How can I hide the autocomplete box in tablet chrome photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNjvp.png)

I want to hide the autocomplete box. (What I draw to grab with blue pen)
It shows when I focus on input tag.
It shows only chrome.
It doesn't show in other mobile browser.

And I am using version 94.0.4606.71 of tablet chrome.

I write the code `autocomplete="no"`, but it shows...
please help me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="password" autocomplete="no" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **on** or **off** instead of **no** that is

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="on/off" />
```

**not**

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="no" />
```

Comment: It didn't work...

Comment: @FreeCutyApple Well I think it is not a autocomplete box but instead it is a option provided to save passwords and other stuff opted by user(Services provided by browsers) which don't be treated as autocomplete(think so) .